# ncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'path' in undefined vue router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3, vue-router4

when I am randomly moving from one component to another on any point vue gives this error and then i can not move another component.

This error is not on any specific component it can happen anywhere.

error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'path' in undefined
    at Object.resolve (vue-router.esm-bundler.js?6c02:2728)
    at matchView (index.esm.js?bec5:446)
    at Array.find (<anonymous>)
    at findViewItemByPath (index.esm.js?bec5:464)
    at Object.findViewItemByRouteInfo (index.esm.js?bec5:424)
    at Object.canStart (index.js?8a30:805)
    at eval (ion-app_8.entry.js?49af:707)
    at canStart (swipe-back-53c5a7dd.js?05d4:8)
    at pointerDown (index-f49d994d.js?14e6:251)
```

Here is my router index.js file

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from '@ionic/vue-router';

import Tabs from '../views/Tabs.vue'
import SignIn from "@/views/Signin.vue";
import Signup from "@/views/Signup.vue";
import { TokenService } from "@/services/token.service";

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    redirect: '/tabs/tab1'
  },
  {
    path: '/search-workers',
    component: () => import('@/views/SearchWorker.vue')
  },
  
  {
    path: '/login',
    component: SignIn,
    meta: {
      public: true,
      onlyWhenLoggedOut: true
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/signup',
    component: Signup,
    meta: {
      public: true,
      onlyWhenLoggedOut: true
    }
  }
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const isPublic = to?.matched?.some(record => record?.meta?.public);
  const onlyWhenLoggedOut = to?.matched.some(
      record => record?.meta?.onlyWhenLoggedOut
  );
  const loggedIn = !!TokenService.getToken();

  if (!isPublic && !loggedIn) {
    return next({
      path: "/login",
      query: { redirect: to?.fullPath }
    });
  }

  if (loggedIn && onlyWhenLoggedOut) {
    return next("/tabs/tab1");
  }

  next();
});

export default router
```

This is how i am using link router in my components

```
<ion-item router-link="/search-workers" v-if="userInfo?.role_id == 9" @click="opened()">
Search Worker
</ion-item>
```

What could be the reason of it? How we can resolve it?

Comment: it usually happens when you forgot to give `to='/'` to `router-link`

Comment: in my case, within createRouter, I used history: createWebHistory, instead of using createWebHistory()

Answer (score 10):

I was facing similar issue but then, it got solved by using
"history: createWebHistory()" instead of "history: createWebHistory". It got resolved by calling it instead of pointing at it.

Answer (score 3):

I just had this issue because, in my App.vue file, I accidentally put

```
<router-link></router-link>
```

instead of

```
<router-view></router-view>
```

Took me a few minutes to figure it out, so check that.

Comment: In my case, i forgot changing `href` to `to` in `<router-link to="/"></router-link>`

Answer (score 3):

for me  `history: createWebHistory` => this is creating error,

solved by calling it as function =>  history: createWebHistory(),

Answer (score 2):

i had same issue, and i solve with add ***to*** property in my router-link

Answer (score 2):

change

```
const router = createRouter({
      history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
      routes
    })
```

to

```
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes
})
```

work for me

Answer (score 1):

Check `process.env.BASE_URL` in `createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL)`.
I had similar issue where I had a typo and had left the config like this: `history:createWebHistory,`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had the following in my Router/index.js file.

```
{
  path: '/contacts',
  name: 'Contacts',
  component: function(){ import('../views/ContactsView.vue'); } 
}
```

So I changed the anonymous function to an *arrow function*

```
{
  path: '/contacts',
  name: 'Contacts',
  component: () => import('../views/ContactsView.vue')
}
```

and it worked. I am a beginner, so I am not sure of the specifics of why it behaved this way.