# Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'path' in undefined not getting solved

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vue-router, vue-router4

i am always getting error  "Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'path' in undefined"
i checked several blogs, it shows that i am doing spell mistake in router file, but even after changing as said the error is not solved.

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import HomeView from '../views/HomeView.vue'
import Product from '../views/Product.vue'
import CartView from '@/views/CartView.vue'

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: HomeView
  },
  {
    path: '/about',
    name: 'about',
   
    component: () => import('../views/AboutView.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/:category_slug/:product_slug/',
    name: 'Product',
    component: Product
  },
  {
    path: '/cart',
    name: 'CartView',
    component: CartView
  }
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})

export default router
```

[error i am geting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LpoD.png)

Comment: The router file looks ok to me.  According to some of the [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67360207/ncaught-typeerror-cannot-use-in-operator-to-search-for-path-in-undefined-vu) it can also be because of a missing `to` prop on `<router-link>`.  Try that and/or show how you're using router-links in your app.